# what are some good ways of calling user defined function from a python library?

Tags: python, design-patterns, global

Let's say I am writing a library module a.py like this

```
def call_func(f):
    """ invoke func by its func str """
    return eval(f)()
```

and the user define function is in module b.py,

```
from a import call_func  
def b():
    return "b"

call_func("b")
```

This will be an error since in module a, function b is not exposed.
Since function b is in user space, from library a point of view, user defined function b is not known.

It might be possible to use a register function in a.py, but I don't know how to do it. Or maybe there are alternative ways?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `eval` <sub>basically</sub> ever.

You could use a dict of functions, and combine that with `globals()` (or maybe better yet have an explicit dict of functions, e.g. `{"b": b}`):

```
def call_func(funcs, f):
    return funcs[f]()

def b():
    print("b was called")

call_func(globals(), "b")
```

Comment: that sure works!! thanks a lot ! @AKX  why do you avoid eval?

Comment: Because `eval()` allows one to run any arbitrary code, not just named functions. If someone would manage to pass `"__import__('os').system('rm -rf ~/*)"` as `f` you would have no home directory left anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the function itself.

**a.py**

```
def call_func(f):
    return f()
```

**b.py**

```
from a import call_func  
def b():
    return "b"

call_func(b)
```

Comment: This could be a good idea for other scenarios. but in this case, the library was design to call user function b through str. Actually it will call user functions ( might be more than one) through a template. So str is preferred.  Thanks for your input...